# How to add a tooltip popup containing social share widgets in a views table

Tags: views, entities, tooltips

I have a views table containing a number of columns, one contains a small icon.
I would like to have a tool tip open (containing the usual share widgets: twitter & facebook) when the image is clicked.

Could anyone suggest a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lots of modules providing tooltip functionality.

If you are familar with php coding:
1. Install Views PHP (https://drupal.org/project/views_php)
2. Install BeatuyTips (https://drupal.org/project/beautytips)
3. Create a PHP-field in your view and add the following code (Best is to include in your own module)

```
function render_socials($data = NULL){

  //if the links and icons are displayed inside the view, you can use $data

  $output .= l(theme('image', array('path' => 'PATH_TO_SOCIAL_ICON')), 'LINK_TO_SOCIAL_PROFILE', array('attributes' => array('class' => array('a.row-' . $data->nid . '-socials-popup')), 'html' => TRUE));
  $output .= l(theme('image', array('path' => 'PATH_TO_SECOND_SOCIAL_ICON')), 'LINK_TO_SOCIAL_PROFILE', array('attributes' => array('class' => array('a.row-' . $data->nid . '-socials-popup')), 'html' => TRUE));
  $output .= l(theme('image', array('path' => 'PATH_TO_THIRD_SOCIAL_ICON')), 'LINK_TO_SOCIAL_PROFILE', array('attributes' => array('class' => array('a.row-' . $data->nid . '-socials-popup')), 'html' => TRUE));
  $output .= l(theme('image', array('path' => 'PATH_TO_ANYOTHER_SOCIAL_ICON')), 'LINK_TO_SOCIAL_PROFILE', array('attributes' => array('class' => array('a.row-' . $data->nid . '-socials-popup')), 'html' => TRUE));
 }


$options['socials_' . $data->nid] = array(
         'cssSelect' => 'a.row-' . $data->nid . '-socials-popup',
         'text' => _render_socials($data),
         'trigger' => array(0 => 'mouseover', 1 => 'click'),
         'width' => 350,
       );
 print beautytips_add_beautytips($options);
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. I will use your answer to get this working and report back.